# Redirect challenge on Centos with reverse proxy on Apache

Tags: apache, redirect, proxy, centos, reverse-proxy

I have installed AllegroGraph on a Linux box with CentOS. I have port 80 open, and set up a virtual host on Apache to redirect traffic from `<serverip>/AllegroGraph` to my Linux box where AllegroGraph is running on port 10035.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin root
ServerName "myserverip"
ServerAlias server

ProxyPass /AllegroGraph/  http://localhost:10035/
ProxyPassReverse /AllegroGraph/ http://localhost:10035/

...

</VirtualHost>
```

The application can be reached this way, however when I run a query I get the following result;

```
Executing query failed:
'/AllegroGraph/repositories/GBA?query=select%20%3Fs%20%3Fp%20%3Fo%20%7B%3Fs%20%3Fp%20%3Fo%7D&queryLn=SPARQL&limit=100&infer=false'
(up from 'AllegroGraph') not found.
```

When I look in the Apache logs I see that the POST contains a double part of the url;

```
POST /**AllegroGraph/AllegroGraph**/repositories/GBA?query=select%20%3Fs%20%3Fp%20%3Fo%20%7B%3Fs%20%3Fp%20%3Fo%7D&queryLn=SPARQL&limit=100&infer=false HTTP/1.1" 404 145 "http://my.server.ip/AllegroGraph/repositories/GBA" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/28.0.1500.95 Safari/537.36"
```

Comment: Is it possible that it's passing it through, getting a 404 from the CentOS, and then in reporting the 404, tacking the `/AllegroGraph` from the ProxyPassReverse on?  After all, `http://my.server.ip/AllegroGraph/repositories/GBA` (without an extra prefix) still appears farther along in that log line.  According to [the AllegroGraph documentation](http://www.franz.com/agraph/support/documentation/v4/server-overview.html#header2-7), it appears that you can log the HTTP traffic on the CentOS VM, and it would be useful to look at its log as well.